# There are $21$ $0$'s and $19$ $1$'s, how many combinations of them can be there so that no two 1's come together

Tags: combinatorics

I approached it as, let $B(m,n)$ represent the no of solutions where $m$ represents no of $0$'s and $n$ represent no of $1$'s, so 
$$B(m,n) = B(m-1,n) + B(m-1,n-1)$$ where $B(m-1,n)$ represents combinations beginning with $0$, and $B(m-1,n-1)$ represents combinations beginning with $10$. I implemented this on computer and this gives correct results.
Are there any other easier methods to solve this

Comment: Write down a string of 21 zeros. They define a total of 22 slots: one at both ends, and twenty between pairs of consecutive zeros. Your task is to distribute those 19 ones into those 22 slots in such a way that only a single one can go to a single slot. How many ways are there to pick the 19 slots you use?

Comment: Your answer talks about strings, but the question (stated in the title) does not mention strings, and has no clear meaning. How many "combinations of them" would there be without the conditio9n "no two 1's come together" (whatever that means)? $2^{40}$ because each of the 0's and each of the 1's can be included or not? Or, if the 0's are indistinguishable, and the 1's are indistinguishable, would it be $22\cdot20=440$ since you can take any number of 0's from 0 to 21, and any number of 1's from 0 to 19? And what does "1's come together" mean? Are the combinations to be *ordered* somehow?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen From your comment, I gather that a "combination" of the given 0's and 1's is a *string* containing all $21$ of the 0's and all $19$ of the 1's. I believe you're right, but I would really like to know how you did that. How did you figure out from the text of the question that that was what the OP meant?

Comment: @bof $0$'s and $1$'s are both indistinguishable, say if we have $3$ zero and $3$ ones then a valid string would be like $010101$, and an invalid one would be like $110100$ and you have to use all the given $0$'s and $1$'s

Comment: In stating the question, maybe you should *say* that "combinations" are strings? To me, "strings" are strings, and "combinations" are (unordered) sets. Couldn't you have just *said*, "How many strings with 21 0's and 19 1's are there, with no two consecutive 1's", if that's what you meant?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That method solved it, thanks :)

Comment: Great! You can flesh that out to an answer or not - your call. I tend to think that this must be at least a near duplicate of an earlier question. May be even the general case has been handled? I don't visit the combinatorics tag too often, so I can't point at one right away.

Comment: @bof is correct.  You should edit your question to replace the word combinations by the word strings throughout.

Answer (score 2):

If we start with 21 '0's and place them in a line that gives us 22 slots (the 20 gaps in between and one at each end) into which we can put our '1's into and we assume for now that each '1' is individually distinguishable then in order for each one to go into a different slot the first '1' can go into any of these 22 slots, the second into any of the 21 remaining the third into any of the remaining 20 and so on.

How many ways can we order these? 19! so since we cant distinguish between our '1's we divide the answer above by 19! to get

$$\dfrac{22 \times 21 \times 20 \times 19 \times ... \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4}{19 \times 18 \times 17 \times 16 \times ... \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 }= \dfrac{22 \times 21 \times 20}{3 \times 2 \times 1} = 1540$$

Comment: Did you mean to say "If we place the $21$ $0$s in a line, that gives us $22$ slots ..."?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I though that was implied but I hope I have clarified it now.

Comment: You should replace the word say with the word start.  Otherwise, it is now fine.

Answer (score 0):

If $w$ is an admissible word remove the zero immediately following the first $18$ ones, and you obtain an arbitrary word $w'$ of length $22$ containing exactly $3$ zeros. There are ${22\choose3}=1540$ such words.